# Using Indy IdTelnet on ipv6 only network

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, indy

Apple App Store requires apps to work on ipv6 only networks.
How to make IdTelnet work on such networks ?

Answer (score 4):

`TIdTelnet` has an `IPVersion` property, but it is declared as `protected` and thus cannot be accessed directly by user code.  In order to set the `IPVersion`, you can declare a hack class, eg:

```
uses
  .., IdStack, IdGlobal, ..

type
   TIdTelnetHack = class(TIdTelnet)
   published
     property IPVersion;    //expose protected property
   end;

procedure TForm1.TelnetConnect(const aHost:String);
var
  aIPVersion: TIdIPVersion;
begin
  if not IdTelnet1.Connected then 
  begin  //not connected. go connect
    // check if ipv6 or ipv4 network, and support both, 
    try
      GStack.ResolveHost(aHost, Id_IPv6);
      aIPVersion := Id_IPV6;
    except
      GStack.ResolveHost(aHost, Id_IPv4);
      aIPVersion := Id_IPV4;
    end;

    IdTelnet1.Host := aHost;   
    IdTelnet1.Port := 8090;   
    TIdTelnetHack(IdTelnet1).IPVersion := aIPVersion;  //set to IPv4 or IPv6

    IdTelnet1.Connect;
  end;
end;
```

To test your app on an IPv6 network, set your Mac as an IPv6 access point, as explained here:

[Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html)

Comment: You don't need to publish the `IPVersion` property explicitly. A descendant class inherits `protected` members, and the class's declaring unit has implicit access to the class's `protected` members. So, `type TIdTelnetHack = class(TIdTelnet);` will suffice in your example.

Comment: Be sure to vote for [this ticket](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/164) in Indy's issue tracker.